# Internal 500 POST error when trying to AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, cross-domain

I'm getting this error:

> POST http://website.com/name-check.php 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

I was using localhost and it was working fine and when I uploaded my files to a online host I got this error. I did some research and I found out it was a Cross-browser error. Could you help me fixing this please. I came across some solutions but I don't really know how to implement them.

This is my name-check.js file:

```js
// Validate confirm password while typing

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name").keyup(function() {
    var name = $(this).val();

    if (name.length > 0) {
      $("#resultname").html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin loading-icon"></i>');


      /*$.post("email-check.php", $("#reg-form").serialize())
    .done(function(data){
    $("#resultmail").html(data);
     });*/

      $.ajax({

        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'name-check.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          $("#resultname").html(data);
        }
      });
      return false;

    } else {
      $("#resultname").html('');
    }

  });


});
```

This is my name-check.php file:

```
<?php

 $host="localhost";
 $user="root";
 $pass="";
 $dbname="lr";

 $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}",$user,$pass);

 if($_POST['name']) 
 {
   $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);

  if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $name )){

       echo "<i class='fa fa-circle user-validation-w pull-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><span class='availability pull-right'> Solo letras</span>";

   } else {

   echo "<i class='fa fa-check user-validation-ok pull-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><span class='availability pull-right'></span>";

 }

 }
 ?>
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

php_flag disply_error on
php_value error_reporting 2039

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^step1/?$ /step1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^step2/?$ /step2.php [L]
```

And when I open the debugger it says that there's an error here:

```
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

Comment: Can I see the code you use to handle and respond to the POST request?

Comment: Internal server error is not the same as a cross-domain error. Internal error means you have a bug in your PHP script, check the Apache log on the server.

Comment: @Diego Please add this parameter to your ajax call - crossDomain : true

Comment: @morsecodist the name-check.php file?

Comment: @Pooja I'll try that

Comment: Yes, though @Pooja 's answer is similar to what my theory was. I thought the issue might be with your response headers. Specifically you could set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: @morsecodist Already tried that. Still not working. I edited the post, my .htaccess and PHP files are there now.

Comment: @Pooja It does not work.

Comment: Hmm... maybe try [JSONP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)?

Comment: @morsecodist Just tried that. Still not working :'(

Comment: This isn't cross-domain AJAX, since you don't have a domain in the URL. It's going to the same domain. A 500 error means there's a problem with the PHP script, check your log file on the server for the reason.

Comment: If the URL has no protocol or host you can remove `crossDomain: true,` and ignore any notion of CORS.

Comment: Does my php file have any error? Or is it the host?